# datagridview autoscroll if some rows are hidden?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm making modifications to a Datagridview that already has some autoscrolling code rigged-up.:

```
            // snap to most recent entry
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    dgvLog.ClearSelection();
                    dgvLog.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvLog.Rows.Count - 1;

                    dgvLog.Invalidate();
                }));   
             }
```

However, there is a checkbox column on this Datagridview that represents "internal" versus "external" log entries.

And the users have asked for a way to filter the Datagridview so that they can look at EITHER external entries OR internal entries... OR (the default) both.  So, I've created a set of radio buttons for that.  The buttons simply loop through the rows, check the value of the boolean, and set each row.Visible to true or false. Those appear to be working nicely.

However, when I filter the Datagridview to show only the "internal" entries, I'll get an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException:   FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property cannot be set to an invisible row.

Any idea how I can take into account row visibility when setting that FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property ??     Not finding much in my Googling efforts.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'm thinking this might work instead??

dgvLog.ClearSelection;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following

```
int lastRow = dgvLog.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
if (lastRow >= 0)
    dgvLog.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = lastRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzstk5f(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the DataGridView.

From the documentation:

> Gets or sets the first cell currently displayed in the DataGridView; typically, this cell is in the upper left corner.

Used like this:

```
var firstDisplayedRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
```

**Not tested myself as I don't have an IDE to hand**